# Sudoku Checker: Accessing 3x3 subgrid in C

Tags: c, arrays, grid, sudoku

I've created a program that lets a user input all the values of a sudoku puzzle that is 9x9, stores those values in an array, and can check if the values in all of the rows and columns are different, but I'm having trouble understanding how i would implement code to focus on each sub grid of 3x3. I'm thinking i would have to have one last nested for loop that gets divided by maybe 3 but I'm completely stuck on this part.

```
int main (void) 
{
int n, i, j, x, array[9][9];
int check=0, sum;

//Enter how many puzzles user wants to solve.
scanf("%d", &n);

/*First for loop going from x to n is used so the user can enter
n amounts of puzzles and so the code doesn't try to
check n amount of puzzle inputs as one massive puzzle.*/
for(x=0;x<n;x++)
    {

    //Loop goes through all of the rows in the puzzle.
    for(i=0;i<9;i++)
        {
            //Loop that goes through all of the columns in the puzzle.
            for(j=0;j<9;j++)
            {
                scanf("%d", &array[i][j]);

            }
        }
    //Checker for loops

    for(i=0;i<9;i++){

        /*Sum initalized to 0 through every iteration so that the
        sum doesn't collect unneeded data from previous calculations
        to determine if inputs are valid. */

        sum=0;

        /*Loop that goes through all columns individually and adds them up
        totals of sum should equal 45 b/c (1+2+3+4...=45). If not check
        is changed. */

        for(j=0;j<9;j++)
            sum+=array[i][j];
        if(sum!=45){
            check=1;
            break;
            }
        }
    /* Same loop but switches the i and j in the array[i][j] to check the rows */
    for(i=0;i<9;i++){
        sum=0;
        for(j=0;j<9;j++)
            sum+=array[j][i];
        if(sum!=45){
            check=1;
            break;
            }
    }
        for (row = (i / 3) * 3; row < (i / 3) * 3 + 3; row++){
            sum=0;
            for (col = (j / 3) * 3; col < (j / 3) * 3 + 3; col++)
                sum+=array[i][j];
            if(sum!=45){
                check=1;
                break;
            }
        }


    //Check used to see if the inputs failed
    if(check==0)
        printf("YES\n");
    else
        printf("NO\n");
}
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will help if you break up your solution into functions handling discrete parts of the problem. Then you could write a function to handle each sub-grid. Makes the problem much more manageable. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void process_sub_grid(int array[9][9], unsigned int start_row,
                      unsigned int start_col)
{
    unsigned int r, c;

    printf("Processing sub-array rows %d-%d, cols %d-%d\n",
           start_row, start_row + 2, start_col, start_col + 2);

    for (r = start_row; r < start_row + 3; r ++) {
        for (c = start_col; c < start_col + 3; c++) {
            printf("Accessing array[%d][%d]\n", r, c);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int array[9][9];
    unsigned int start_row, start_col;

    for (start_row = 0; start_row < 9; start_row += 3) {
        for (start_col = 0; start_col < 9; start_col += 3) {
            process_sub_grid(array, start_row, start_col);
        }
    }
}
```

Running that program gives:

```
Processing sub-array rows 0-2, cols 0-2
Accessing array[0][0]
Accessing array[0][1]
Accessing array[0][2]
Accessing array[1][0]
Accessing array[1][1]
Accessing array[1][2]
Accessing array[2][0]
Accessing array[2][1]
Accessing array[2][2]
Processing sub-array rows 0-2, cols 3-5
Accessing array[0][3]
Accessing array[0][4]
Accessing array[0][5]
Accessing array[1][3]
Accessing array[1][4]
Accessing array[1][5]
Accessing array[2][3]
Accessing array[2][4]
Accessing array[2][5]
Processing sub-array rows 0-2, cols 6-8
Accessing array[0][6]
Accessing array[0][7]
Accessing array[0][8]
Accessing array[1][6]
Accessing array[1][7]
Accessing array[1][8]
Accessing array[2][6]
Accessing array[2][7]
Accessing array[2][8]
Processing sub-array rows 3-5, cols 0-2
Accessing array[3][0]
Accessing array[3][1]
Accessing array[3][2]
Accessing array[4][0]
Accessing array[4][1]
Accessing array[4][2]
Accessing array[5][0]
Accessing array[5][1]
Accessing array[5][2]
Processing sub-array rows 3-5, cols 3-5
Accessing array[3][3]
Accessing array[3][4]
Accessing array[3][5]
Accessing array[4][3]
Accessing array[4][4]
Accessing array[4][5]
Accessing array[5][3]
Accessing array[5][4]
Accessing array[5][5]
Processing sub-array rows 3-5, cols 6-8
Accessing array[3][6]
Accessing array[3][7]
Accessing array[3][8]
Accessing array[4][6]
Accessing array[4][7]
Accessing array[4][8]
Accessing array[5][6]
Accessing array[5][7]
Accessing array[5][8]
Processing sub-array rows 6-8, cols 0-2
Accessing array[6][0]
Accessing array[6][1]
Accessing array[6][2]
Accessing array[7][0]
Accessing array[7][1]
Accessing array[7][2]
Accessing array[8][0]
Accessing array[8][1]
Accessing array[8][2]
Processing sub-array rows 6-8, cols 3-5
Accessing array[6][3]
Accessing array[6][4]
Accessing array[6][5]
Accessing array[7][3]
Accessing array[7][4]
Accessing array[7][5]
Accessing array[8][3]
Accessing array[8][4]
Accessing array[8][5]
Processing sub-array rows 6-8, cols 6-8
Accessing array[6][6]
Accessing array[6][7]
Accessing array[6][8]
Accessing array[7][6]
Accessing array[7][7]
Accessing array[7][8]
Accessing array[8][6]
Accessing array[8][7]
Accessing array[8][8]
```

Comment: I see what you're saying! thank you, this really helped alot!

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has already been answered but I wanted to contribute what I learned for any future programmers who find this question and would like to try it a different way.

I was just working on this and after some trial and error I discovered a way to map the "index" of the 3x3 sub-grid to its upper left bound row and column (i, j) index.

Say you have:

```
 012 345 678
-------------
| 0 | 1 | 2 |
-------------
| 3 | 4 | 5 |
-------------
| 6 | 7 | 8 |
-------------
```

(And you can imagine the row indices 012, 345, 678 are to the
left of the grid arranged similarly to the column indices on top.)

If you wanted to determine the index of a sub-grid using the current row and column you could use the formula found in this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2051928/963986 by converting your row and column indices to a one dimensional index and plugging it in:

```
int len = board.size(); // board size: 9
int index = row * len + col; // convert 2d indices to 1d index
int x = sqrt(len); // square root of 9 is 3
int box_index = (index % len) / x + x * (index / (len * x));
```

With the box index you could then determine the row and column upper left bounds:

```
int row_start = box_index % x * x; // x is the same as above
int col_start = box_index / x * x;
```

With that you now have the row and column indices to start iterating the 3x3 sub-grid. Your lower right bounds would be `row_start + x - 1` and `col_start + x - 1`.

Notably this method is only suitable for a matrices with a perfect square root. I have not tested this on a matrix with dimensions other than 9x9, 4x4, etc.